# OS X Xcode/clang to build Windows executables?

Tags: c, windows, xcode, clang

Is it possible to build classic Windows executables (Windows 8 support is not required) from C source code using the latest Xcode/clang compilers on a current Mac (e.g. without using gcc or a VM to run Linux or Windows)?

Comment: You might take a look at the Cocotron project.

Answer (score 3):

After thinking `why the hell would you want to do this?`, I just surprised myself and found what may actually be a solution!

[The Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org)

> > The Cocotron is an open source project which aims to implement a cross-platform Objective-C API similar to that described by Apple Inc.'s Cocoa documentation. This includes the AppKit, Foundation, Objective-C runtime and support APIs such as CoreGraphics and CoreFoundation.

Also see this blog post: [Win-win with Cocotron and Xcode 4.3 — code for Mac, build for Windows (Part 1)](http://lacquer.fi/pauli/blog/2012/02/win-win-with-cocotron-part-1/)

Although the last entry on the Cocotron site was from 2010 - so it may or may not still be alive